# border-radius is not working in Firefox for me on input types

Tags: html, input, css

Everything works fine in webkit browsers. But when i'm trying to use border-radius with input[type="url"] it doesn't work. Not even just using input. Nothing still works.

Css

```
 section.crypter input {
  border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  }
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="url" placeholder="Insert URL" />
    <input type="button" value="Crypt" />
  </form>
```

Why isn't Firefox letting me style the input?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you need to style the border first :

```
input {
border:1px solid #666666;
  border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius :15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  }
```

Comment: I did :) Sorry wouldn't let me earlier.!